# Call a Python function from C and consume a 2D Numpy array in C

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to figure out, how I could achieve this:

I'm having a Python script, which in the end produces a Numpy array, an array of arrays of floats, to be more specific. I have all properly set: I can pass parameters from C to Python, launch Py functions from C, and process returned scalar values in C.

What I'm currently not being able to do, is to return such a Numpy array as a result of a Py function to C.

Could somebody probably provide me a pointer, how to achieve this?

TIA

Comment: Could you show what you have tried till now?

Comment: What do you mean by "return such a Numpy array as a result of a Py function to C"? Store the returned numpy array to an array of `float`-s?

Comment: Could you illustrate with a short example what exactly are you trying to achieve? If I understand it right you need to store the output of the python function called from a C program to some C variables, right?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @RahulBharadwaj: Right now I didn't have tried anything, since I have no clue. I'm just able to return a scalar from python. 
Basically it is a list at python level, a list containing 192 lists of 640 floats each, which I need to pass up to C

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look at is Inter Process communication (IPC). There are several ways to perform it.

You can use one of:

- Files (Easy to use)
- Shared memory (really fast)
- Named pipes
- Sockets (slow)

See [Wikipedia's IPC page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and find the best approach for your needs.

Comment: No, I already have the Python script plus interpreter running within the C app. https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small working demo example (**1D, not 2D array!** it's not perfect, adjust to your needs).

```
# file ./pyscript.py
import numpy as np

# print inline
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.inf)
x = np.random.random(10)
print(x)
# [0.52523722 0.29053534 0.95293405 0.7966214  0.77120688 0.22154705 0.29398872 0.47186567 0.3364234  0.38107864]
```

~ demo.c

```
// file ./demo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
        int fd[2];
        pipe(fd); // create pipes
        char buf[4096];

        pid_t pid=fork();
        if (pid==0) { // child process

                dup2(fd[1],1);
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);

                char *pyscript = "./pyscript.py";
                char *args[] = {"python3", pyscript, (char*)NULL};
                execv("/usr/bin/python3",args);

        }
        else {
                int status;
                close(fd[1]);
                int bytes = read(fd[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
                printf("Python script output: %.*s\n", bytes, buf);

                char* values[10];
                int count = 0;
                values[count++] = &buf[1]; // ignore the '[' coming from numpy array output
                char* p = buf;
                while (*p) {
                        if (*p == ' ') {
                                *p = 0;
                                values[count++] = p + 1;
                        }
                        p++;
                }

                float a[10];
                float f;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        printf("%f\n", f = atof(values[i]) ); // float values
                        a[i] = f;
                }

                waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Sample output

```
# cc demo.c
# ./a.out
Python script output: [0.23286839 0.54437959 0.37798547 0.17190732 0.49473837 0.48112695 0.93113395 0.20877592 0.96032973 0.30025713]

0.23286839
0.54437959
0.232868
0.544380
0.377985
0.171907
0.494738
0.481127
0.931134
0.208776
0.960330
0.300257
```

`a` will be your desired result, an array of `float`.

Comment: Thanks, but this was not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One has to use the PyList API for decoding list objects from Python to C

https://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/list.html?highlight=m

Solved.